# Get array of all active category ID's

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, array, category-id

How do I **get an array containing the ID's of all active categories**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$activeCategories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```